# See if user has bookmarked object in list

Tags: django, templates, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a `ListView` in Django where I list all objects. Some of the objects are bookmarked by the authenticated user.

Each object has a relation `bookmarks = GenericRelation(Bookmark)`.

How can I check if the user who sees the `ListView` has bookmarked each specific object?

I think it will cost many sql queries if I check it in the template.

## Edit

My `Bookmark` model:

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

My `Post` model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    bookmarks = generic.GenericRelation(Bookmark)
```

My list view:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'resource/post_list.html'
```

My guess would be that I need to make a method `get_queryset()` in which I for each object check if a bookmark object exists with `user=self.request.user`.

## Edit 2

I don't want to filter anything. I want all objects in the model but when I am looping through my queryset in the template I want to determine if the authenticated user has bookmarked the specific object. So I think I will need to populate each object in the queryset with an extra field telling if the user has bookmarked the specific object or not. I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you share your Bookmark model and the listed object models with their fields?

Comment: I've added my models and list view to my question.

Comment: I've tried to help you and made some research - Django doesn't provide "conditional annotations" so I think you have three ways how you can resolve your problem: **1)** use django extra, but I have issue with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716843/django-extraselect-cannot-get-access-to-current-column-value-django-co **2)** write custom aggregation function like that https://gist.github.com/vinilios/225997 and use it with django `annotate` **3)** define two querysets and simply combine them in your template

Comment: solved issue so post solution soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** using django extra https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
    annotated_qs = qs.extra(select=OrderedDict([('bookmarked', 'SELECT CASE WHEN user_id = %s THEN "true" ELSE NULL END FROM resource_bookmark WHERE object_id = resource_post.id AND content_type_id = %s'), ('has_voted', 'provide_some_query_that_returns_one_column_and_one_row'), ]), select_params=[self.request.user.id, ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model).id])

    return annotated_qs
```

Main idea is that you can access in your extra select statement to `some_app_post`.`bookmarks_id` in each row, select `bookmarks` object using that id and add to this row extra column `bookmarked` value depending on the condition `bookmarks__user=self.request.user`

Comment: It seems to be different with `GenericRelation` :-(

I get `no such column: some_app_post.bookmarks_id`.

Comment: Replace some_app_bookmark by Bookmark table name (in your Database) and some_app_post by Post table name.

Comment: for example you have app `bookmark` and model there `Bookmark`, so django by default create for this model table with name `bookmark_bookmark` and for model `Post` in app `bookmark` it should be `bookmark_post` ... but anyway you should look that names in your database

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did replace the names as you said. I just didn't change the names in my comment :-) I don't think it's correct to use `bookmarks_id` for a `GenericRelation` but I don't know what sql syntax it uses

Comment: on the weekend I will try implement second solution - custom class for annotation, main goal get something like this: `qs.annotate(bookmarked=IfEqual('bookmarks__user', self.request.user, 'success_value'))`

Comment: I would love to see the second solution! :-D I guess it could also be used to check if user has voted on a specific object.

Comment: can you using Django shell print here generated SQL query? just `python manage.py shell` import `Post` and there `print Post.objects.extra(...).query`

Comment: and also can you show all columns names in your Post table in database?

Comment: SELECT (SELECT CASE WHEN `resource_bookmark`.`user_id` = 1 THEN "true" ELSE NULL END FROM `resource_bookmark` WHERE `resource_bookmark`.`id` = `resource_post`.`bookmarks_id`) AS "bookmarked", "resource_post"."id", "resource_post"."user_id", "resource_post"."parent_id", "resource_post"."lft", "resource_post"."rght", "resource_post"."tree_id", "resource_post"."level" FROM "resource_post" ORDER BY "resource_post"."tree_id" ASC, "resource_post"."lft" ASC

Comment: It seems that `resource_post` doesn't have any relation to `resource_bookmark` so I probably have to do something like this: WHERE `resource_bookmark`.`object_id` = `resource_post`.`id`'

Comment: yes I've read docs `object_id` stores primary key values from the models you’ll be relating to

Comment: and add `content_type__pk` to model `Post` like here `b = Bookmark.objects.get(url='https://www.djangoproject.com/')
>>> bookmark_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(b)
>>> TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type__pk=bookmark_type.id,
...                           object_id=b.id)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: because `object_id` stores primary key values from **number** of models so you should specify content_type for Post model

Comment: Post.objects.extra(select=OrderedDict([('bookmarked', 'SELECT CASE WHEN user_id = %s THEN "true" ELSE NULL END FROM books_authors_bookmark WHERE object_id = books_authors_post.id AND content_type_id = %s'),]), select_params=[custom_user.id, ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post).id])

Comment: Great! What if I want to add multiple extra fields (has_voted etc.)? Can it be done smart or will I have to add the fields to the list and insert the user_id in `select_params` multiple times?

Comment: yes since it is `OrderedDict` - ordered dictionary, you can pass so many `(key, values)` pair as you want

Comment: I've updated answer, and if you need additional param - simply add it to `select_params` list and put `%s` where in query it should be

Answer (score 2):

I have a somewhat simpler setting where objects can have fans (users) as a ManyToMany relationship. My solution to mark which items have been "liked" by the current user is to add a list to the context with the ids of the models and then check this list in the template. It may not be the most efficient way but it is fast enough for me.

You might need to tweak it to adapt it to your generic relationship, but the code goes like this:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'resource/post_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context['user_favs'] = Post.objects.filter(
                bookmarks__username=self.request.user.username).values_list(
                'id', flat=True)
        return context
```

Template:

```
{% if item.id in user_favs %}
... Your special code here ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: yes it is a third solution mentioned in my comment to question :)

Comment: You were talking about two querysets, this is much simpler.

Comment: ok, you've upgraded second queryset - by selecting only `id`s from model and made list from it , but idea the same - there are two queries: **1)** SELECT * FROM resource_bookmark **2)** SELECT `books_authors_post`.`id` FROM `books_authors_post` INNER JOIN `books_authors_bookmark` ON ( `books_authors_post`.`id` = `books_authors_bookmark`.`object_id` AND (`books_authors_bookmark`.`content_type_id` = 11 )) INNER JOIN `auth_user` ON ( `books_authors_bookmark`.`user_id` = `auth_user`.`id` ) WHERE `auth_user`.`username` = some_user_username bookmarks__username=self.request.user.username)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [the documentation for Django's ListView class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), I found that this class inherits from the `django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin` class, among others. This means that your intuition was correct. You will need to override the `get_queryset()` method that the `ListView` class inherits from the `MultipleObjectMixin` class.

[From the documentation about `get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

> Get the list of items for this view. This must be an iterable and may be a queryset (in which queryset-specific behavior will be enabled).

This simply means that you should override this method to return the queryset containing the objects you want the ListView to display to the user. Your intended behavior was to filter the Post objects displayed in the ListView to only display Post objects for which the user has an existing bookmark.

There is the additional issue of how to get the user object for filtering. The `get_queryset()` method does not appear to receive the `request` object, so we can't directly access the `request.user` in this method. In the documentation for the Django ListView, there is a brief flowchart that explains which methods are called for this view, and it what order.

According to this flowchart, the `dispatch()` method is run first. More importantly, it is run before the `get_queryset()` method, so we can store data from the dispatch method for later use in the get_queryset method. You can get a copy of the user during the `dispatch()` method of your view ([documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch)).

First of all, override the `dispatch()` method so that you can keep a copy of the request.user for later use in `get_queryset()`. Like so:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = request.user
    return super(PostListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is an example of how to override `get_queryset()` to filter only the Post objects which have a bookmark associated with the current User object:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset_with_all_posts = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
    queryset_for_only_this_user = queryset_with_all_posts.filter(bookmarks__user=self.user)
    return queryset_for_only_this_user
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want all objects in the model but when I am looping through my queryset in the template I want to determine if the authenticated user has bookmarked the object. So I think I will need to populate each object in the queryset with an extra field telling if the user has bookmarked the specific object or not. I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: If you use the query filter I provided above for finding posts that are bookmarked by a given user, it will work. It uses a secondary field lookup on the bookmarks field of the Post model. `filter(bookmarks__user=self.user)` will return only Posts with at least one bookmark that holds a reference to the provided user.

Comment: If you are looking to create a new column which indicates whether a user has bookmarked a Post or not, you might try [looking at using annotation to accomplish this task](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).

Comment: I don't want to filter anything. I just need extra information added to my queryset. It seems that annotation is only for summaries/aggregates.

Comment: You may want to update your question with the information in your comments here. This was not clear before.